# Where does the mysterious blue bar and question mark come from (when logged in as admin)?

Tags: views, theming

When I'm logged in as an admin, I see a blue bar at the top of the page, with a question mark in a circle, but no text. This is how it looks like:

[image]

And the markup is:

```
<div class="region region-help alert alert-info">
```

I guess it's some kind of alert, but obviously there's no text, and nothing I can see in any of the logs that might be related either.

Anyone knows what this might be and how to fix it?

Comment: Well that is a bootstrap alert with the class `alert-info`.  http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#alerts By default that alert doesn't show up with the theme/sub theme so i'm guessing it came from a bootstrap related module or from some custom code. hard to determine because you can put code for a bootstrap alert basically anywhere

Answer (score 0):

I think You should try to:

- search Your modules or themes directory for usage of **drupal_set_message** function or **dsm** if You are using devel module.
- check trigger module settings for User under admin/structure/trigger/user
- check theme template for empty container with alert-info class